# What is the acquired advantage theory in international trade?

Tags: international-trade

Is it the comparative advantage or absolute advantage or something all together different?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "acquired advantage theory" in international trade. Adam Smith used the term "acquired advantage" (e.g. through acquired skills in production) to distinguish it from a "natural advantage" (e.g. through abundant resources) one country has over another country. Both are parts of what would now be called an absolute advantage.